Как спроектировать базу данных товаров с кросс-номерами?
База данных для интернет-магазина автозапчастей, использую EF Core, ASP NET Core и SQL Server.
На сервер будет загружаться определенное количество прайс-листов 1 раз в день.
В прайс-листах могут быть одинаковые товары, но не во всех прайс-листах для товаров будут указаны кросс-номера.
Прайс-лист это список товаров на определённом складе, в базе данных должны быть по листу такие столбцы:
Бренд
Наименование
Артикул
Цена
Количество
Номер склада
Кросс-номера(Некоторое количество строк через точку с запятой, для поиска взаимозаменяемых товаров)

Изначально я сделал одну таблицу, кросс-номера каждого товара загружались в одну ячейку без разбития на атомарные значения.
Соответственно на сайте для поиска аналогов товара нужно обратиться к базе данных, найти все строки совпадающие с этим товаров по "Бренд+Артикул", собрать все кросс-номера в этих строках, потом снова найти совпадения с каждым из полученных кросс-номеров и вернуть аналоги.
Я подумал, что можно синхронизировать все кросс-номера после загрузки новых прайс-листов, т.е брать каждый товар, находить аналогичный товар по "Бренд+Артикул",совмещать их кросс-номера в строку, убирать повторения, и двум товарам присваивать эту строку. Решение настолько медленное, что процесс на весь день.
Далее в поисках проблемы думал про нормализацию и это показалось мне решением, ибо думал я лишь о эффективности поиска.
Из таблицы товаров удалил столбец кросс-номеров, создал отдельную таблицу CrossNumbers, в ней три столбца - Бренд, Артикул, Кросс-номер(1 значение) каждая строка должна быть уникальна(иначе количество строк в таблице увеличится в разы). В итоге при загрузке для каждого кросс-номера нужно так же проверять нет ли такой же строки в БД(по 3 значениям Бренд+Артикул+Кросс-номер).
Поиск то я сделал эффективным, но теперь прайс-листы будут весь день загружаться) Теперь я в тупике.
Извиняюсь если много лишнего текста.

Ну, если используется EF Core и Sql Server, могу посоветовать посмотреть на JSON. Смотрите в документации пункты Primitive collections и Enhancements to JSON column mapping.

Непонятно, откуда у вас берутся проблемы с производительностью. Если каждый день не загружаются миллионы документов и если записей не миллиарды, то всё должно работать быстро. Показывайте код и конкретные запросы.

Не понятно, кросс номер - это номер чего? Причём тут бренд и артикул? Сколько кросс номеров на один товар в среднем и максимум? Кто и как часто это читает? Как часто кросс инфа меняется? Как часто инфа по продукту меняется?  Примеры данных? Что конкретно пробовали и где конкретно тормозило?

Кросс-номер - это номер, что определяет являются ли две запчасти взаимозаменяемы.
Каждый бренд содержит свои артикулы, потому конкретный товар определяется по бренду+артикулу. На один товар максимум +-30 номеров, в среднем 5-10. Читаться они будут регулярно пользователями для поиска аналогов товаров. Кросс инфа меняется 1 раз в день при загрузке прайс листов. То что пробовал описал в вопросе, но это далеко не всё)
В целом я уже решил проблему, разрешил дубликаты в бд, убрал тысячу проверок, после загрузки всех прайс листов ищу дубликаты в бд и удаляю, для 500 тысяч строк скорость приемлемая


Я бы добавил в прайс индексированный ItemId=Бренд+Артикул.
Кроссномер в прайсе оставил, как написано в начале.
В CrossNumbers объединил Бренд и Артикул в ItemId.

Если что-то тормозит, то нужно смотреть код.

Спасибо за ответ, хоть я уже и решил проблему(кратко описал решение выше), но объединение Бренда и Артикула хоть как дополнительно повысит эффективность.
Но да, проблема была в коде, плохо понимаю во что транслируются мои LINQ запросы и как они вместе работают, когда нужно одновременно собирать данные, обеспечивать уникальность проверяя значения в БД и с нового источника, и загружать.
Ну и думаю мои изначальные варианты решения я мог бы сделать приемлемыми по скорости.
Но не понял 2 пункт, зачем дублировать значения кросс-номеров загружая их в две таблицы? Или что вы имели в виду?

Дублирование (если делается автоматически и не создаёт искажений информации), может помочь в ускорении работы. На мой общий взгляд, кроссномера в прайсе нужно оставить, может быть, только для отображения человеку. Но вы сами обдумайте этот вопрос, так как я не знаю вашей системы, а вы знаете всё досконально.

Ну в моем случае это бы не ускорило работу. Ведь нужно смотреть не кросс-номера товара с одного прайс-листа, а кросс-номера этого товара со всех прайс листов.
Но на некоторых аналогичных сайтах так не делают, из-за этого пользователям нужно тратить намного больше времени на поиск товаров, но вместо этого они идут на другие сайты (со слов самих пользователей)
Ну и про отображение человеку - кросс-номерам ни в каком виде на сайте присутствовать нельзя, как я понял это дорогая информация, но сам не знаю весь путь кросс-номеров
